# Tomcat 9 Mobicents Sip Servlet

Tags: tomcat, sip, restcomm, mobicents, mss

Does Apache Tomcat 9 MSS Edition (including Mobicents Sip Servlet) exist?
If so, where can I download it?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

No we haven't integrated yet with tomcat 9 as it is not released as GA yet but is this something you would like to contribute? Also mobicents has been rebranded to restcomm so it's restcomm sip servlets now.

Comment: Hi, i am interested in integrating the mss to Tomcat 9.0.30 . I've already made some POC, and managed to breakthrough at least as Proxy sip server. I am willing share the code with the community. contact me

Comment: Please do a Pull request for the benefit of others.